STM32 based boost converter noise on Rfb
I had designed a boost converter and control its duty cycle using the stm32f446ZE. My boost conveter is designed for 50-312V, 10A. I need feedback voltage but on reading that on oscilloscope I am getting a very noisy signal which is causing my Vfb to be variating alot, I have used RC combinations but nothing worked. I have made the setup by soldering components on a veroboard.
The output Vfb is shown below:


I have tried various combinations of RC filters but nothing worked. This is damaging by micrcontroller as well. Kindly help me solve this issue. My switching frequency is 50kHz and inductor is 700uH while capacitor is 2000uF.
This is my circuit layout



Using a veroboard to breadboard power electronics circuits is not going to give you the best results.  A good PCB layout is the best way to go.  Other than that, we need a schematic and a picture of your setup and connections to have any hope of improving anything.

But how shall I test my circuit before going to PCB

I know this vero shall cause noise. But I need to do testing before going for PCB stage

You can't. You either order an evaluation board for the circuit from the manufacturer or you make it yourself. PCBs start at 5 USD.

The Veroboard looks clean, with thick traces. The sensing network shall be placed very close to the input pin of the error amplifier: $R_{lower}$'s ground goes to the IC or op-amp GND pin directly while the middle point of the divider goes to the sensing input. $R_{upper}$ is connected close to $R_{lower}$ and then a longer trace can go sensing $V_{out}$. But if  $R_{upper}$ is too far from the sensing input, you may collect noise. Also, you can increase the bias current in the sensing bridge if it helps. Is the power supply stable, did you check crossover versus RHP zero position?

@VerbalKint I just did the Matlab simulation to compute PID variables. Can you give me some reference to find any compensation circuit in feedback..because on lower voltages the switching noise is not high. But with higher voltage noise gets so high that my MOSFETs are getting damaged. Am now trying to use TVS to eliminate some spikes. My feedback goes directly into microcontroller I am using.

You should check my newly-released book for compensation examples ^_^

@VerbalKint I am facing another issue of IGBT leaking. I am getting some minor spikes initially on the IGBT gate which further increases with time and eventually increases so much so that the IGBT fails and shorts out. What  can be done to remove these spikes and avoid this heating on IGBT. The mosfet though gave much stable results.

I have checked various combinations of gate resistors but It didnt helped out.

As stated by @John D in this comment,

Using a veroboard to breadboard power electronics circuits is not going to give you the best results. A good PCB layout is the best way to go. Other than that, we need a schematic and a picture of your setup and connections to have any hope of improving anything.

